# ntoskrnl blocking port 8080

Tags: windows-8, port

I'm trying to run a web service that usually listens on port 8080, but there's another service on my computer that is currently listening on that port.  (the process now appears to be using port 8081)

After a little bit of research, I was able to determine that the ntoskrnl.exe process was listening on that port.

It has only been using that port for the last 2 weeks, so somethin'gs changed

Can anyone help me figure out why it's using that port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit was RavenDB which was installed along the NServiceBus package.

[I found the solution on this NServiceBus related group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/13787)

basically typing the following into the command line.

```
C:\Program Files\NServiceBus.Persistence\Raven.Server.exe /uninstall
```

Thank you to David Murray for the `Open your browser and type: //localhost:81/` remark.

I typed `localhost:8080` into my browser and it brought me to a raven-DB page, which started me on the right track.

Answer (score 4):

Check if you have IIS installed. Turn it off if its on and then check port 8080. I know ntoskrnl.exe runs if IIS is installed.

To change the port for IIS:

- In Start menu Search option, type: IIS and click Internet Information
  Services Manager  or simply do a run command: inetmgr .
- Under Connections, You’ll see your PC name click on it to expand the
  list. Now you can see “Sites” click on it to expand.
- Under Sites you can see Default Web Site, right click on it and
  Select EDIT BINDINGS. Edit HTTP binding port from 80 to 81.
- Open your browser and type: //localhost:81/.